# Why is the outer unit normal unique for $C^k$ boundaries

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

Let $U$ be a bounded open set with $C^k$-boundary, i.e. there is a $C^k$-function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $$U=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:f(x)>0\}, \quad \partial U=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:f(x)=0\} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \nabla f(x)\neq 0, \ x\in\partial U. $$ We can define outer unit normal $\nu$ at the boundary $\partial U$ as $$\nu(x)=-\frac{\nabla f(x)}{|\nabla f(x)|}, \ x\in\partial U.$$ My question is, why $\nu$ is well-defined, i.e. independent of the choice of $f$? If there is another function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the same conditions as $f$, does it follow that $\nu_f=\nu_g$? Can this be generalized for less smooth boundaries? All help is welcome.

Comment: Do you know some differential geometry? Since the given conditions imply $\partial U$ is a $C^1$ submanifold, $\nabla f^\perp$ and $\nabla g^\perp$ are both the tangent space to $\partial U$ and thus $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are proportional.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis yes I do know differential geometry. but why the proportionality constant is positive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we are given $\nabla f \ne 0$ wherever $f=0$, we know $0$ is a regular value for $f$ and thus (by the regular value theorem) $\partial U$ is a $C^1$ submanifold, with tangent space $$T_x \partial U = \ker df(x) = \nabla f(x)^\perp.$$
The same argument applies  to $g,$ so we know that $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are proportional. Since $\nu$ is manifestly unit-length, we just need to check that $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ point in the same direction, i.e. $\langle \nabla f, \nabla g \rangle > 0$. To do so, we consider the curve $$\gamma(t) = x + t \nabla f(x)$$ for small $t$. Since $\gamma'(0) = \nabla f(x)$, the chain rule tells us $(f \circ \gamma)'(0) = |\nabla f|^2 > 0$; so we know $f(\gamma(t)) > 0$ for small positive $t$. This means the curve is moving in to $U$ (by the fact $U = \{ f > 0 \}$); so we must also have $g(\gamma(t)) > 0$ for small positive $t$ and $g(\gamma(0))=0.$ Thus $$(g \circ \gamma)'(0) = \nabla g \cdot \gamma'=\langle \nabla f, \nabla g \rangle \ge 0.$$ Since we already know the vectors are nonzero and proportional, this inequality must be strict, so we are done.

Regarding the regularity, we just need the domain (i.e. $f,g$) to be $C^1$, both to define the normal in the first place and for the regular value theorem to work. I don't think anything less smooth will give you a globally defined normal vector; but if you're willing to accept an almost-everywhere normal then you should be able to replace $C^1$ with Lipschitz.

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot! so the fact for Lipschitz-boundaries comes from Rademacher's theorem?

Comment: Yes, though this only obvious if you define Lipschitz domains as those that are locally the region under the graph of a Lipschitz function - if you want to use a level-set definition instead you'd have to check it's equivalent, which I'm not sure is even true.

Comment: okay, thanks. to be careful, I should also show that the level sets of $f$ and $g$ define exactly the same tangent space, i.e. tangent space is independent of the chosen coordinates?

Comment: Well, it depends what you want to take as your starting point - if you're taking the basics of differential geometry as given then this is unnecessary. If you wanted to start from more elementary material, you could use the implicit function theorem to show that the velocities of differentiable curves in $\partial U$ passing through $x$ are exactly those in $\nabla f^\perp$ and likewise $\nabla g^\perp$, so these spaces must coincide.